# How activate Privatemsg Module to all users?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, private-messaging

I just enabled the [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) Module in my Drupal 6. I would like to enable this module to all users, who join in the website. But the registered users cannot see the **"Write new message and Messages"** link.

Why the  Privatemsg is not active in users section ?

Comment: Crossed to: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/how-activate-privatemsg-module-to-all-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `http://yoursite.com/admin/user/permissions` and set the permissions you want for the `privatemsg` module to the `Authenticated User` role (or whatever role you're trying to enable this for).